# ReportLab first page different (cover page)

Tags: python, reportlab

I am creating a PDF report using python 3.7.9 and latest reportlab. I am trying to assign a different `template` to my first page (without header and footer), but my attemps do not work. This setup is based on the [documentation, chapter 9.5](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf).
How can I use a different `template` only on my first page?

Below code creates a PDF with a simple table of contents and header and footer on all pages.

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle as PS
from reportlab.platypus import PageBreak, Table
from reportlab.platypus.paragraph import Paragraph
from reportlab.platypus.doctemplate import PageTemplate, BaseDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.tableofcontents import TableOfContents
from reportlab.platypus.frames import Frame
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.lib import colors
from functools import partial

class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):

    def __init__(self, filename, **kw):
        self.allowSplitting = 0
        BaseDocTemplate.__init__(self, filename, **kw)

        template = PageTemplate('normal',
                                [Frame(1.75*cm, 2.5*cm, 17.5*cm, 24*cm, id='F1')],
                                onPage=partial(header_and_footer,
                                header_content=header_content,
                                footer_content=footer_content))

        self.addPageTemplates(template)

    def afterFlowable(self, flowable):
        "Registers TOC entries."
        if flowable.__class__.__name__ == 'Paragraph':
            text = flowable.getPlainText()
            style = flowable.style.name
            if style == 'Heading1':
                self.notify('TOCEntry', (0, text, self.page))
            if style == 'Heading2':
                self.notify('TOCEntry', (1, text, self.page))

h1 = PS(name = 'Heading1',
       fontSize = 14,
       leading = 16)

h2 = PS(name = 'Heading2',
       fontSize = 12,
       leading = 14,
       leftIndent = 5)
l0 = PS(name = 'list0',
        fontSize = 12,
        leading =14,
        leftIndent=0,
        rightIndent=0,
        spaceBefore = 12,
        spaceAfter =0
        )

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'Header and Footer'
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
def header(canvas, doc, content):
    canvas.saveState()
    w, h = content.wrap(doc.width, doc.topMargin)
    content.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin-22.4, doc.height + doc.bottomMargin + doc.topMargin - h-25)
    canvas.restoreState()

def footer(canvas, doc, content):
    drawPageNumber(canvas, doc)
    canvas.saveState()
    w, h = content.wrap(doc.width, doc.bottomMargin)
    content.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin-22.4, h)
    canvas.restoreState()

def header_and_footer(canvas, doc, header_content, footer_content):
    header(canvas, doc, header_content)
    footer(canvas, doc, footer_content)

def drawPageNumber(canvas, doc):
    pageNumber = canvas.getPageNumber()
    canvas.setFont("Arial",11)
    canvas.drawCentredString(17.4*cm, 1.35*cm, 'Page '+str(pageNumber))

def PageNumber(canvas, doc):
    return(canvas.getPageNumber())

header_center_text='header_center_text foo'
footer_center_text='footer_center_text bar'  


    
def create_deco():
    global header_content, footer_content
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    'Header'
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    Header_caption=((header_center_text))
    A='Author'
    Header_table_data=[['',Header_caption,'Author:',Paragraph(f"""<font fontSize=7> {A} </font>""")],
                       ['','','Date:','11.22.3333'],
                       ['','','Version:','123']]
    
    Header_table=Table(Header_table_data,colWidths=[4*cm,9.5*cm,1.6*cm,2.4*cm],rowHeights=[0.66*cm,0.66*cm,0.66*cm],style=[
    ('GRID',(0,0),(1,2),1,colors.black),
    #('ALIGN',(0,0),(1,0),'CENTER'),
    ('ALIGN',(0,0),(0,3),'CENTER'),
    ('VALIGN',(0,0),(3,2),'MIDDLE'),
    ('ALIGN',(2,0),(3,2),'RIGHT'),
    ('SPAN',(0,0),(0,2)),
    ('SPAN',(1,0),(1,2)),
    ('BOX',(2,0),(-1,-1),1,colors.black),
    #('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(3,0),colors.Color(49/255,71/255,137/255))
    ])
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    'Footer'
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    Footer_caption=(footer_center_text)
    Seitenzahl=''
    Footerer_ID=Seitenzahl
    
    Footer_table_data=[['',Footer_caption,Footerer_ID]]
    Footer_table=Table(Footer_table_data,colWidths=[4*cm,9.5*cm,4*cm],rowHeights=[1*cm],style=[
    ('GRID',(0,0),(2,0),1,colors.black),
    #('ALIGN',(0,0),(1,0),'CENTER'),
    ('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'RIGHT'),
    ('VALIGN',(0,0),(2,0),'MIDDLE'),
    ('ALIGN',(0,0),(3,0),'CENTER'),
    #('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(3,0),colors.Color(49/255,71/255,137/255))
    ])
    
    footer_content = Footer_table
    header_content = Header_table
create_deco() 



'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'Build story'
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
# Build story.
story = []
toc = TableOfContents()
# For conciseness we use the same styles for headings and TOC entries
toc.levelStyles = [h1, h2]
story.append(Paragraph('This is my cover page where I wish I had no header and footer!', l0))
story.append(PageBreak())
story.append(Paragraph('TOC HERE', l0))
story.append(toc)
story.append(PageBreak())
story.append(Paragraph('First heading', h1))
story.append(Paragraph('Text in first heading', PS('body')))
story.append(Paragraph('First sub heading', h2))
story.append(Paragraph('Text in first sub heading', PS('body')))
story.append(PageBreak())
story.append(Paragraph('Second sub heading', h2))
story.append(Paragraph('Text in second sub heading', PS('body')))
story.append(Paragraph('Last heading', h1))

doc = MyDocTemplate('mintoc.pdf')
doc.multiBuild(story)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution myself, to whom it may concern:

The `templates` are defined in the class `MyDocTemplate`.
To change the template, insert `story.append(NextPageTemplate('#YourTemplateHere'))` into the story, following pages will use this template.

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle as PS
from reportlab.platypus import PageBreak, Table, NextPageTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.paragraph import Paragraph
from reportlab.platypus.doctemplate import PageTemplate, BaseDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.tableofcontents import TableOfContents
from reportlab.platypus.frames import Frame
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.lib import colors
from functools import partial

class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):

    def __init__(self, filename, **kw):
        self.allowSplitting = 0
        BaseDocTemplate.__init__(self, filename, **kw)

        template_CoverPage = PageTemplate('CoverPage',[Frame(1.75*cm, 2.5*cm, 17.5*cm, 24*cm, id='F1')],)
        template_NormalPage = PageTemplate('NormalPage',
                                [Frame(1.75*cm, 2.5*cm, 17.5*cm, 24*cm, id='F1')],
                                onPage=partial(header_and_footer,
                                header_content=header_content,
                                footer_content=footer_content))

        self.addPageTemplates([template_CoverPage,template_NormalPage])



    def afterFlowable(self, flowable):
        "Registers TOC entries."
        if flowable.__class__.__name__ == 'Paragraph':
            text = flowable.getPlainText()
            style = flowable.style.name
            if style == 'Heading1':
                self.notify('TOCEntry', (0, text, self.page))
            if style == 'Heading2':
                self.notify('TOCEntry', (1, text, self.page))

h1 = PS(name = 'Heading1',
       fontSize = 14,
       leading = 16)

h2 = PS(name = 'Heading2',
       fontSize = 12,
       leading = 14,
       leftIndent = 5)
l0 = PS(name = 'list0',
        fontSize = 12,
        leading =14,
        leftIndent=0,
        rightIndent=0,
        spaceBefore = 12,
        spaceAfter =0
        )

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'Header and Footer'
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
def header(canvas, doc, content):
    canvas.saveState()
    w, h = content.wrap(doc.width, doc.topMargin)
    content.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin-22.4, doc.height + doc.bottomMargin + doc.topMargin - h-25)
    canvas.restoreState()

def footer(canvas, doc, content):
    drawPageNumber(canvas, doc)
    canvas.saveState()
    w, h = content.wrap(doc.width, doc.bottomMargin)
    content.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin-22.4, h)
    canvas.restoreState()

def header_and_footer(canvas, doc, header_content, footer_content):
    header(canvas, doc, header_content)
    footer(canvas, doc, footer_content)

def drawPageNumber(canvas, doc):
    pageNumber = canvas.getPageNumber()
    canvas.setFont("Arial",11)
    canvas.drawCentredString(17.4*cm, 1.35*cm, 'Page '+str(pageNumber))

def PageNumber(canvas, doc):
    return(canvas.getPageNumber())

header_center_text='header_center_text foo'
footer_center_text='footer_center_text bar'  


    
def create_deco():
    global header_content, footer_content
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    'Header'
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    Header_caption=((header_center_text))
    A='Author'
    Header_table_data=[['',Header_caption,'Author:',Paragraph(f"""<font fontSize=7> {A} </font>""")],
                       ['','','Date:','11.22.3333'],
                       ['','','Version:','123']]
    
    Header_table=Table(Header_table_data,colWidths=[4*cm,9.5*cm,1.6*cm,2.4*cm],rowHeights=[0.66*cm,0.66*cm,0.66*cm],style=[
    ('GRID',(0,0),(1,2),1,colors.black),
    #('ALIGN',(0,0),(1,0),'CENTER'),
    ('ALIGN',(0,0),(0,3),'CENTER'),
    ('VALIGN',(0,0),(3,2),'MIDDLE'),
    ('ALIGN',(2,0),(3,2),'RIGHT'),
    ('SPAN',(0,0),(0,2)),
    ('SPAN',(1,0),(1,2)),
    ('BOX',(2,0),(-1,-1),1,colors.black),
    #('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(3,0),colors.Color(49/255,71/255,137/255))
    ])
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    'Footer'
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    Footer_caption=(footer_center_text)
    Seitenzahl=''
    Footerer_ID=Seitenzahl
    
    Footer_table_data=[['',Footer_caption,Footerer_ID]]
    Footer_table=Table(Footer_table_data,colWidths=[4*cm,9.5*cm,4*cm],rowHeights=[1*cm],style=[
    ('GRID',(0,0),(2,0),1,colors.black),
    #('ALIGN',(0,0),(1,0),'CENTER'),
    ('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'RIGHT'),
    ('VALIGN',(0,0),(2,0),'MIDDLE'),
    ('ALIGN',(0,0),(3,0),'CENTER'),
    #('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(3,0),colors.Color(49/255,71/255,137/255))
    ])
    
    footer_content = Footer_table
    header_content = Header_table
create_deco() 



'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
'Build story'
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'
# Build story.
story = []
toc = TableOfContents()
# For conciseness we use the same styles for headings and TOC entries
toc.levelStyles = [h1, h2]
story.append(NextPageTemplate('CoverPage'))
story.append(Paragraph('This is my cover page where a different template is used!!!', l0))
story.append(NextPageTemplate('NormalPage'))
story.append(PageBreak())
story.append(Paragraph('TOC HERE', l0))
story.append(toc)
story.append(PageBreak())
story.append(Paragraph('First heading', h1))
story.append(Paragraph('Text in first heading', PS('body')))
story.append(Paragraph('First sub heading', h2))
story.append(Paragraph('Text in first sub heading', PS('body')))
story.append(PageBreak())
story.append(Paragraph('Second sub heading', h2))
story.append(Paragraph('Text in second sub heading', PS('body')))
story.append(Paragraph('Last heading', h1))


doc = MyDocTemplate('mintoc.pdf')
doc.multiBuild(story)
```